# During debugging dialog windows often disappear

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

My team and I have recently migrated from Visual studio 2010 to Visual studio 2015. The issue we keep getting is that dialog windows opened by our application keep disappearing. This happens for example when we switch to debugger prior to opening the dialog window and the window opens while we do step by step execution during debugging.

When that happens it's impossible to continue debugging since program is stuck at Form.ShowDialog and Dialog cannot be seen. I've tried Alt+Tab which worked in the older version of Visual Studio 2010 but there rarely happened and it was fixable quickly. Here is just frustrating and session needs to be restarted.

Our dialog windows are basic forms with some custom painting of title bars and borders. Because of this customisation forms do override WndProc to handle resizing. Not sure if it's relevant or not.

Any advice would be great either how to explore the issue or how to find the dialog and bring it up.  Thank you.

Comment: Minimize all windows one by one then click back on visual studio or the application window.  I find then that the dialog will show up.  using show desktop doesn't always work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip except that the debugged app cannot be minimized since the dialog is opened 'somewhere'...

Comment: No of course not not while debugging.  This exact same thing happens to me while using metro framework. Minimize all other Windows the dialogue will show.